# SQL Query - Same filter (obviously not) but huge performance difference

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have a query that contains this filter:

```
... 
WHERE P.CustomerId = @CustomerId 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PaymentRestriction RS 
                      WHERE RS.CustomerId = P.CustomerId )
```

and it does not execute in 5 min. I tried to change the parameter with real value:

```
 ... 
WHERE P.CustomerId = '79579DFB-5610-48E0-A585-08D97867AA1F'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PaymentRestriction RS 
                      WHERE RS.CustomerId = P.CustomerId )
```

But nothing changed, then I tried something different and it executed  in just one sec. :

```
... 
WHERE (P.CustomerId = @CustomerId OR P.CustomerId = '79579DFB-5610-48E0-A585-08D97867AA1F')
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PaymentRestriction RS 
                      WHERE RS.CustomerId = P.CustomerId )
```

I changed indexes and used `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` but nothing changed.Where should I control and change? Is it related to statistics? If it is, how can I fix?

PS: It is a long query and has many other filters also. But I guess, the problem is clear.

**Edit 1:** I changed the query filters in the question according to related parts.

**Edit 2:** I found that the join part is also affecting the performance. If I delete join part, there is no problem in all conditions. I simplified the query that problem still exists. Here is my simplified query:

```
SELECT      COUNT(0)
FROM        Payment (NOLOCK) P
LEFT JOIN   PaymentFile (NOLOCK) PF
            ON  PF.PaymentFileId = P.PaymentFileId 
WHERE    -- (P.CustomerId = @Customer OR P.CustomerId = '79579DFB-5610-48E0-A585-08D97867AA1F')
            (P.CustomerId = @Customer)
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PaymentRestriction RS 
                            WHERE    RS.CustomerId = P.CustomerId )
```

Another interesting results:

- If I replace `COUNT(0)` with `*`, the execution time drops from 45 sec. to 20 sec.
- If I uncomment the first filter line and comment the second filter line, the execution time drops from 45 sec to 0.1 sec
- If I remove the last filter `NOT EXIST`, the execution time drops from 45 sec. to 0.1 sec again.

Comment: `It is a long query and has many other filters also. But I guess, the problem is clear.`  The other filters are key here.  Have you correctly parenthesised your conditions here?  If you are just bolting an `or` at the end, your query can skip a lot of processing.

Comment: What is the datatype for CustomerId in actual table ? and what is the datatype used for  @CustomerId? some times irrelevant datatypes wil go under internal conversion which leads to performance issue

Comment: @ShakeerMirza Both are uniqueidentifier.

Comment: @iamdave Parentheses are correct. But I controlled the other filter parts and edited the question according to your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the execution plans of both versions?

Comment: @CustomerId  is a Stored Procedure parameter or a local variable inside the stored procedure? may be 'parameter sniffing'..

Comment: @AbdulRasheed It is not a stored procedure parameter. I am executing the query directly from sql server management studio.

Comment: Do you actually have 2 columns in both tables, `Customer` and `CustomerId`, or is it just a typo?

Comment: @RogerWolf It is just a typo. Thanks, I am editing and sharing simplified all query to be more precise.